# I have a code for a stored procedure to create a table .But it returns error message while executing.Can any one please help me to solve this?

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE new_SP
(
    @tablename varchar(50)
)
AS  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xxx varchar(50)
    SET  @xxx= 'CREATE TABLE '+@tablename+'( name VARCHAR (50))'
    PRINT @xxx
    EXEC (@xxx)
```

Comment: What is this error message? Post it please

Comment: After putting END are you getting any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least immediately, I notice you are missing the `end`:

```
create procedure new_SP ( @tablename varchar(50)

)
as
  begin
    declare @xxx varchar(50)
    set  @xxx= 'create table '+@tablename+'( name varchar (50))'
    print @xxx
    exec (@xxx)
  end  -- you are missing this
```

If you add the `END`, then this should work.  Just tested it in SQL Server 2008, using `exec dbo.new_SP test` and it resulted in a table.

## See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ae11/1)